# What is the equivalent of Math.Round() with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7

How do I use c# similar `Math.Round` with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` in Delphi?

What will be the equivalent of:

```
double d = 2.125;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Output: `2.13`

In Delphi?

Comment: I don't think there is an out-of-the-box function that does that. There is up, down, to-wards zero and banker's rounding, but no AwayFromZero, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is [SimpleRoundTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Math.SimpleRoundTo) function in combination with [SetRoundMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/SetRoundMode_(Delphi)). As the documentations says:

> **SimpleRoundTo** returns the nearest value that has the specified power of ten. In case `AValue` is exactly in the middle of the two nearest values that have the specified power of ten (above and below), this function returns:
>
> - The value toward plus infinity if `AValue` is positive.
> - The value toward minus infinity if `AValue` is negative and the FPU rounding mode is not set to rmUp

Note that the second parameter to the function is `TRoundToRange` which refers to exponent (power of 10) rather than number of fractional digis in .NET's [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8) method. Therefore to round to 2 decimal places you use -2 as round-to range.

```
uses Math, RTTI;

var
  LRoundingMode: TRoundingMode;
begin
  for LRoundingMode := Low(TRoundingMode) to High(TRoundingMode) do
  begin
    SetRoundMode(LRoundingMode);
    Writeln(TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(LRoundingMode));
    Writeln(SimpleRoundTo(2.125, -2).ToString);
    Writeln(SimpleRoundTo(-2.125, -2).ToString);
  end;
end;
```

> rmNearest
>
> 2,13
>
> -2,13
>
> rmDown
>
> 2,13
>
> -2,13
>
> rmUp
>
> 2,13
>
> -2,12
>
> rmTruncate
>
> 2,13
>
> -2,13

Comment: But beware that setting the rounding mode for this is using a global change to solve a local problem. This might cause problems (multi-threading, libraries, etc.).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That's correct. Delphi 7 (and even newer versions) is plagued with these global state dependent routines and as pointed out in the comment and other answer, it should be used with care.

Answer (score 15):

I believe the Delphi RTL's [SimpleRoundTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Math.SimpleRoundTo) function does essentially this, at least if the FPU rounding mode is "correct". Please read its documentation and implementation carefully, and then decide if it is good enough for your purposes.

But beware that *setting* the rounding mode for a single rounding operation like this is using a global change to solve a local problem. This might cause problems (multi-threading, libraries, etc.).

Bonus chatter: Had the question been about "regular" rounding (to an integer), I think I'd tried an approach like

```
function RoundMidpAway(const X: Real): Integer;
begin
  Result := Trunc(X);
  if Abs(Frac(X)) >= 0.5 then
    Inc(Result, Sign(X));
end;
```

instead.

Of course, it is possible to write a similar function even for the general case of *n* fractional digits. (But be careful to handle edge cases, overflows, floating-point issues, etc., correctly.)

**Update:** I believe the following does the trick (and is fast):

```
function RoundMidpAway(const X: Real): Integer; overload;
begin
  Result := Trunc(X);
  if Abs(Frac(X)) >= 0.5 then
    Inc(Result, Sign(X));
end;

function RoundMidpAway(const X: Real; ADigit: integer): Real; overload;
const
  PowersOfTen: array[-10..10] of Real =
    (
      0.0000000001,
      0.000000001,
      0.00000001,
      0.0000001,
      0.000001,
      0.00001,
      0.0001,
      0.001,
      0.01,
      0.1,
      1,
      10,
      100,
      1000,
      10000,
      100000,
      1000000,
      10000000,
      100000000,
      1000000000,
      10000000000
    );
var
  MagnifiedValue: Real;
begin
  if not InRange(ADigit, Low(PowersOfTen), High(PowersOfTen)) then
    raise EInvalidArgument.Create('Invalid digit index.');
  MagnifiedValue := X * PowersOfTen[-ADigit];
  Result := RoundMidpAway(MagnifiedValue) * PowersOfTen[ADigit];
end;
```

Of course, if you'd use this function in production code, you'd also add at least 50 unit test cases that test its correctness (to be run daily).

**Update:** I *believe* the following version is more stable:

```
function RoundMidpAway(const X: Real; ADigit: integer): Real; overload;
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  DoubleResolution = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
  PowersOfTen: array[-10..10] of Real =
    (
      0.0000000001,
      0.000000001,
      0.00000001,
      0.0000001,
      0.000001,
      0.00001,
      0.0001,
      0.001,
      0.01,
      0.1,
      1,
      10,
      100,
      1000,
      10000,
      100000,
      1000000,
      10000000,
      100000000,
      1000000000,
      10000000000
    );
var
  MagnifiedValue: Real;
  TruncatedValue: Real;
begin

  if not InRange(ADigit, Low(PowersOfTen), High(PowersOfTen)) then
    raise EInvalidArgument.Create('Invalid digit index.');
  MagnifiedValue := X * PowersOfTen[-ADigit];

  TruncatedValue := Int(MagnifiedValue);
  if CompareValue(Abs(Frac(MagnifiedValue)), 0.5, DoubleResolution * PowersOfTen[-ADigit]) >= EqualsValue  then
    TruncatedValue := TruncatedValue + Sign(MagnifiedValue);

  Result := TruncatedValue * PowersOfTen[ADigit];

end;
```

but I haven't fully tested it. (Currently it passes [900+ unit test cases](https://privat.rejbrand.se/RoundMidpAwayUnitTests.pas), but I don't consider the test suite quite sufficient yet.)

Comment: Might be a good idea to inline `RoundMidpAway(const X: Real): Integer;`.

Comment: `RoundMidpAway(2.135, -2)` results `2.13`. should be `2.14`

Comment: @zig: Yeah, floating-point numbers _are_ indeed difficult to work with, as hinted. In my defence, I suspected such issues could be present, thus my comment about extensive testing (which I intended to perform tonight). In this case, `RoundMidpAway(2.135, -2)`, yields `MagnifiedValue = 213.5` and `Abs(Frac(X)) = 0.499999999999972`, instead of the exact value `0.5`. That's the reason. I'll try to fix this.

Comment: thanks. may I ask why you use `Real` type instead of `Double` or `Extended` (like `SimpleRoundTo` does)?

Comment: @zig: I saw (in CodeInsight and documentation) that both `System.Round` and `System.Trunc` use `Real` for the argument, and so I wanted to do the same. But, of course, currently (and likely in the future, too) `Real` is the same thing as `Double`. (You can see that I assume double precision in my choice of the fuzz constant.) You likely need to tweak the constants if you want to support `Single` and `Extended` (only present in 32-bit apps); then overload `RoundMidpAway`.

Comment: The thing is, if I change the `Real` to `Extended` parameters, the fuzz logic is not needed for the 2.135 anomaly. however if I hold that number in a `Double` *variable* and pass it to `SimpleRoundTo` or `RoundMidpAway` (with `Extended` parameters) I get the wrong result again. and I'm scratching my head to understand why...

Comment: But the above does not happen with your final version. both for `Double` and `Extended` *variables*. I didn't test deeply yet.

Comment: That's how floating-point numbers work. If you store a value in a `double`, which cannot be represented exactly, you lose information that can never be recovered. It won't help to upgrade it to an `extended` later. Try `d := 2.135; e := 2.135; Writeln(extended(d) = e);`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to create overloads for `SimpleRoundTo` and `RoundMidpAway` to work with `Extended`?

Comment: My later version treats floating-points the way floating-points should be treated: by assuming some epsilon uncertainties. Thus, if the fractional part is a tiny bit below 0.5, I assume that's because of numerical issues, and still regard it as >= 0.5. The `1E-15` constant is especially suitable for `double`.

Comment: @zig: Yes. And then I'd try `ExtendedResolution = 1E-19 * FuzzFactor;` instead of `DoubleResolution   = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;`. But beware! If you compile for 64-bit, `extended` is merely an alias for `double`!